# Card displacement in Unity

Tags: unity, card-game

Following a tutorial on Youtube, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P66SSOzCqFU, I'm  trying to make a card game that uses dragged cards. When I drag a card it's supposed to stay centered with the mouse, but it's showing up on the edge of the screen when I start to drag it. How do I make it so the card drags with my mouse instead? Currently I'm using two scripts, one for a drop zone and one for "draggable". When I tried to debug the draggable section it kept referring me back to a line in my drop zone script that just had a '{'. I'm working in Unity 5.6.0f3 and Visual Studio 2017. 
My drop zone code looks like this:

```
public class DropZone : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler {

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    //Debug.Log("OnPointerEnter");
    if (eventData.pointerDrag == null)
        return;
        Draggable d = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<Draggable>();
    if (d != null)
    {
        d.placeholderParent = this.transform;
    }
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    //Debug.Log("OnPointerExit");
    if (eventData.pointerDrag == null)
        return;
    Draggable d = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<Draggable>();
    if (d != null && d.placeholderParent==this.transform)
    {
        d.placeholderParent = d.parentToReturnTo;
    }
}

public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log(eventData.pointerDrag.name + "was dropped on" + gameObject.name);

    Draggable d = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<Draggable>();
    if(d != null)
    {
        d.parentToReturnTo = this.transform;
    }
}
}
```

And my Draggable code looks like this:

```
public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {

public Transform parentToReturnTo = null;
public Transform placeholderParent = null;

GameObject placeholder = null;

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("OnBeginDrag");

    placeholder = new GameObject();
    placeholder.transform.SetParent(this.transform.parent);
    LayoutElement le = placeholder.AddComponent<LayoutElement>();
    le.preferredWidth = this.GetComponent<LayoutElement>().preferredWidth;
    le.preferredHeight = this.GetComponent<LayoutElement>().preferredHeight;
    le.flexibleWidth = 0;
    le.flexibleHeight = 0;

    placeholder.transform.SetSiblingIndex(this.transform.GetSiblingIndex());

    parentToReturnTo = this.transform.parent;
    placeholderParent = parentToReturnTo;
    this.transform.SetParent(this.transform.parent.parent);

    GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) 
{
    //Debug.Log("OnDrag");

    this.transform.position = eventData.position;

    //if(placeholder.transform.parent != placeholderParent)
    //    placeholder.transform.SetParent()

    int newSiblingIndex = placeholderParent.childCount;

    for(int i=0; i<placeholderParent.childCount; i++)
    {
        if(this.transform.position.x < placeholderParent.GetChild(i).position.x)
        {
            newSiblingIndex = i;

            if(placeholderParent.transform.GetSiblingIndex() < newSiblingIndex);
            newSiblingIndex--;
            break;
        }
    }

    placeholder.transform.SetSiblingIndex(newSiblingIndex);

}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("OnEndDrag");
    this.transform.SetParent(parentToReturnTo);
    this.transform.SetSiblingIndex(placeholder.transform.GetSiblingIndex());
    GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;

    Destroy(placeholder);
}
```

In the draggable code,
if(placeholder.transform.parent != placeholderParent)
    placeholder.transform.SetParent()
is commented out because that's where I stopped in the tutorial in order to go back and fix my displacement issue.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your code, we can't do much without it :)